# Rolling mechanism

Tags: classical-mechanics

Suppose a ball is rolling on a flat platform.The ball is in a state of pure rolling i.e the point of contact of ball with the surface is having an instantaneous tangential velocity of zero relative to the surface.

From what I understand this is due to nature of friction which tries to stop relative motion and here in case of pure rolling it is successful in doing so.Let us assume that at that instant only a small particle is really in contact with the surface.Which would mean that this single particle is having a relative velocity of zero for that instant.Now since there is no relative motion any longer friction need not act anymore.

However as the very next infinitesimal particle intends to touch the surface it would have a relative velocity with respect to the surface.Subsequently friction would come into effect and resist the motion..and when relative motion comes to zero friction again stops working.

My question is that is the description for mechanism correct and does that imply that friction acts intermittently in case of pure rolling?

Comment: Ideally for pure rolling friction does no work and so $\boldsymbol{F} \cdot \boldsymbol{v}=0$ which implies that either friction $\boldsymbol{F}=0$ or relative velocity $\boldsymbol{v}=0$ (or both).

Comment: Isn't it an absolute necessity that relative velocity has to be zero

Comment: And isn't it so that friction provides a counter torque to make that relative velocity zero at point of contact.So indeed it seems friction acts until relative velocity exists.Isnt it so?

Comment: Yes, friction enforces the no-slip constraint and only exists if the body needs to accelerate, or there is an external torque applied that needs counteracting.